# ZF2 - show jQuery Ui Dialog

Tags: php, jquery-ui, zend-framework2

I want to pop-up a jQuery Ui Dialog, but it doesnt work. Instead of dialog, i get a new page opened. My code is next:

Controller's action:

```
public function diaAction()
{   
    $viewModel = new ViewModel();
    $viewModel->setTerminal(true);        
    return new ViewModel();
}
```

index.phtml:

```
<a class="some-link" title="title here" href="<?= $this->url('dialog', array('action' => 'dia'))?>">open form</a>
```

dia.phtml (dialog code)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.some-link').each(function() {
        var $link = $(this);
        var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
            .load($link.attr('href'))
            .dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                title: $link.attr('title'),
            });
    });
});
</script>
```

I just don't get it, why this is not as simple as it should be. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You have to handle 'click' so it show the dialog instead of following a link. Something like this:

```
$('.table a.button').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('<div></div>')
      .load($link.attr('href'))
      .dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        title: $link.attr('title'),
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried like that to, but it doesn't work. It still opens a new page.

Comment: Then there has to be an error somewhere in your JavaScript. `e.preventDefault()`, is the first that happens when you click the link and it does exactly what it states, it prevents the default action from happening. If it doesn't, the JS doesn't get executed at all, so somewhere prior has to be a JS error, search for it :)

Comment: I have simple zf2 form button (not submit button!) with a class "createContact" and successfully use the example provided by @Sam : $('.createContact').on('click',function(e){ ... .load('<?php echo $this->url('contact', array('action' => 'add')); ?>') ... } - But for some reason I had to remove the autoOpen: false option. Otherwise no dialog would open after the link was loaded via AJAX.

Comment: @Webdevilopers open your own question :P code in comments = killer

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the javascript is just not at its right place. It is called by the index.phtml, not the dia.phtml. How can it be executed it the browser just doesn't know the existence of it?
I think my answer comes too late for you but I hope it will help some other people.